# scala implicit ordering on generic Option[Any] types

Tags: scala, lambda, functional-programming

i am trying to define ordering on data types with Option[Any] but getting error as "method compare overrides nothing"

below is code:-

```
 implicit def ordering[Option[A]]: Ordering[Option[A]] = new Ordering[Option[A]] {
    override def compare[A](x: A, y: A)(implicit ord: Ordering[A]): Int = {
    ord.compare(x,y)
    }
  }
```

---

this whole code to build binary search tree using mutable list with generic any type

```
import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer
import math.Ordering
import Numeric.Implicits._

class  treeUsingList[A]( treeList:ListBuffer[Option[Any]] ){
  println("A greeter is being instantiated")

  var  lst = treeList

  var size= treeList.length


    lst=buildtree(lst)

  implicit def ordering[Option[A]]: Ordering[Option[A]] = new Ordering[Option[A]] {
    override def compare[A](x: A, y: A)(implicit ord: Ordering[A]): Int = {
    ord.compare(x,y)
    }
  }


  def buildtree[A](inputLst:ListBuffer[Option[A]]): ListBuffer[Option[Any]]={

    var j=0
    var k=0
    var lst = ListBuffer[Option[Any]]()

    for (i<- inputLst){
            lst = this.addNode(lst, i , 0)
    }

    lst
  }


  def addNode[A](treeLst:ListBuffer[Option[A]] , item :A , idx:Int)(implicit order: Ordering[Option[A]]):ListBuffer[Option[A]] ={


    if (order.lt(treeLst(idx) , Some(item)) ){

      if(treeLst.length < idx*2+1){
        while(treeLst.length < idx*2+1){
          treeLst.append(None)
        }
        treeLst.append(Some(item))
      }
      else{
        if(treeLst(idx*2+2)==None){
          treeLst(idx*2+2)= Some(item)
        }
        else{
          addNode(treeLst,item ,idx*2+2 )
        }
      }
    }

    treeLst
  }


}




object mainTree{
  var b = scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[Option[Any]](Some(5),Some(2),Some(3),Some(1),Some(7))
  var atree = new treeUsingList[Int](b)
  print(atree)
}
```

Comment: Why the use of `Any`?

Comment: var b = scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[Int]()
scala> b.append(None)
<console>:13: error: type mismatch;

i can append anything into listbuffer of Any
scala> var b = scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[Option[Any]]()
b: scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[Option[Any]] = ListBuffer()

scala> b.append(None)

scala> b.append("cat")
scala> b.append(Some("cat"))
scala> b
res22: scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[Option[Any]] = ListBuffer(Some(1), None, Some(cat))

Comment: i want to have generic tree, if i use list with Int type etc then i have difficulty in adding None and will only work with Int types. So i created with ListBuffer[Option[Any]]

Comment: I think you should read up on generics, there's a bunch of incorrect assumptions here. Any means discarding type information, so you can't differentiate anymore if it's an `Int` or anything else. So you also can't write code that behaves differently if you have `Int` or `String`. Almost all of the time, an `Any` showing up in your code means you did something wrong.

Comment: i used Any type because if tomorrow if i have listbuffer of cars or listbuffer of rectangles. I can override compare method and implement for type "Cars" and "rectangles"   . In example i showed just for Int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think no need define ordering object. You can use `math.Ordering.OptionOrdering`. 
An instance of `OptionOrdering[Int]` can be create with  `math.Ordering.Option[Int]`

Following code can compile, but still have some bug.

```
import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer
import math.Ordering._
import Numeric.Implicits._

class  treeUsingList[A]( treeList:ListBuffer[Option[A]])(implicit order: Ordering[Option[A]]){
println("A greeter is being instantiated")

var  lst = treeList

var size= treeList.length


lst=buildtree(lst)


def buildtree(inputLst:ListBuffer[Option[A]]): ListBuffer[Option[A]]={

  var j=0
  var k=0
  var lst = ListBuffer[Option[A]]()

  for (i<- inputLst){
    lst = addNode(lst, i , 0)
  }
  lst
}


def addNode(treeLst:ListBuffer[Option[A]] , item :Option[A] , idx:Int)(implicit order: Ordering[Option[A]]):ListBuffer[Option[A]] ={
    if (order.lt(treeLst(idx) , item) ){

    if(treeLst.length < idx*2+1){
      while(treeLst.length < idx*2+1){
        treeLst.append(None)
      }
      treeLst.append(item)
    }
    else{
      if(treeLst(idx*2+2)==None){
        treeLst.update(idx*2+2, item)
      }
      else{
        addNode(treeLst,item ,idx*2+2 )(order)
      }
    }
  }

  treeLst
}
}

object mainTree{
  var b = scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[Option[Int]](Some(5),Some(2),Some(3),Some(1),Some(7))
  var atree = new treeUsingList[Int](b)(math.Ordering.Option[Int])
  print(atree)
}
```

Comment: i want to build generic bst tree class. It could handle tomorrow listBuffer of vehicles or Rectangles also if i override compare method using match and case for Rectangle and vehicle class.

Comment: Do the Rectangle and vehicle sortable? I think they should be sortable, then you can create an implicit ordering for them, so when you create the bst tree instance, you can create an OptionOrdering for it,

Comment: For example when you create a treeUsingList[Rectangle] , you can 

var b = collection.mutable.ListBuffer(.....)

var atree = new treeUsingList(b)(math.Ordering.Option[Rectangle])

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit difficult to determine what you're trying to achieve because the code is doing a number of things that are confusing or just plain wrong.

```
override def compare[A]( . . .
                    ^^^
```

This type parameter shadows the one defined in the `class` definition, which means the `A` in the `compare()` method is different from the `A` outside of it.

```
override def compare[A](x: A, y: A)(implicit ord: Ordering[A]): Int = . . .
^^^^^^^^                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The `trait` member you're trying to override doesn't have a 2nd parameter group so this doesn't match.

```
def ordering[Option[A]]: . . .
             ^^^^^^^^^
```

Here you're creating a type parameter called "`Option[A]`" which is a goofy name for a type parameter and it doesn't mean what you think it does.

---

So here's something that compiles. Probably not what you're looking for, but it compiles, and that's not a bad place to start.

```
class treeUsingList[A](treeList:ListBuffer[Option[Any]]) {
  . . .
  implicit def ordering: Ordering[Option[A]] = new Ordering[Option[A]] {
    override def compare(x: Option[A], y: Option[A]): Int = {
      implicitly[Ordering[Option[A]]].compare(x, y)
      //probably better to unpack x and y before comparing
    }
  }
  . . .
}
```